# Login Password not accepted after Killall command on logged in user

Tags: login, password, home-directory, username

I am new to Ubuntu and experiencing an issue after below mentioned action performed.

- installed Ubuntu (dual boot) in windows 7
- created username "aslam" while installing Ubuntu (everything running fine)
- changed display username from aslam to ashahid using user management window in IDE (running fine)
- tried to change core username via terminal from "aslam" to "ashahid" to match login username using a command (probably `usernmode -l oldusername newusername`)
- then i came to know about a command KILLALL which i used for currently logged in user :-(

After last step when I tried to reboot, the login screen was showing username "ashahid" but password not accepted.
I tried to go through Recovery Mode and root login, there was still listed `/home/aslam` but still unable to login.

Please help......

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare this to a real life example:

- You went to the local government to change your name
- you filled in the forms, but did the change yourself (logged in as yourself, IDE user management)
- you went behind the counter and filed all documents yourself as well (logged in as yourself: `usernmode -l oldusername newusername`)
- then you shot yourself in the head (kill all for the currently logged in user)
- And now, **being dead, you're trying to operate on yourself at home without a doctor?**

Nah, that one won't work...

You *can* recover using the root password [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/165248/344926) but the *easiest thing to do now* is to read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (you're user type 4) and re-install and do it right the first time, and create 2 users while you're at it!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)